# LWC Export with proper reference to this and template using settimeout

Tags: lightning-web-components

Trying to learn how to properly reuse code. Basics of a clock updating every second. Would like to  reuse the JS code for different UI LWC but running into various issues

Basic structure

```
/lwc 
......Account LWC 
.............HTML, JS, CSS, Meta 
......Clock LWC (Service)
.............JS
```

UI say for account. Maybe one for case or contact. This code would be repeated (currently)

**UI Javascript**

```
import {LightningElement, api, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'
import { getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { Clock } from 'c/clock';

export default class AccountTzClock extends LightningElement {
    timeIntervalInstance;
    accountRecord;

    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Account.Name', 'Account.UTC_Offset_Minutes__c', 'Account.GoogleAPI_Exception_Message__c'] })
    dataLoaded(result){
        if(result.data){
            this.accountRecord = result.data;
            this.startClock();
        }

    }

    startClock() {
        let utcos = getFieldValue(this.accountRecord, 'Account.UTC_Offset_Minutes__c') | 0;

        if(Clock.updateClock( this, utcos)) {
            this.timeIntervalInstance = setInterval(Clock.updateClock(this, utcos), 1000)
        }else{
            //Do stuff
        }
    }

    get errorMsg(){
        return getFieldValue(this.accountRecord, 'Account.GoogleAPI_Exception_Message__c');
    }


}
```

The LWC Service JS that I would like to reuse is the JS that actually updates the clock. I have gotten to the point where it works on load. Not sure if there is a better way to gain access to the template and `this` other than passing in `this` like I am.

The problem now is that I cannot get `setInterval` to work. I get "bind must be called on a function" but I have tried to placed bind in every conceivable place to no avail. (Yea I am green)

Any suggestions on the best way to reuse this service class and be able to use setTimeout with access to `this` from the caller to gain access to the callers properties and template?

**Clock Service JS**

```
    const updateClock = (that, utcOffset) => {
        if(that.errorMsg != null){
            return false;
        }

        var date = new Date();
        var h = date.getUTCHours(); // 0 - 23
        var m = date.getUTCMinutes(); // 0 - 59
        var s = date.getUTCSeconds(); // 0 - 59
        var o = utcOffset;

        var hAdj = o / 60;
        var session = "AM";

        //Local Hour
        h = h + hAdj;

        //Rollover code
        if( h < 0){
            h = 24 + h;
        }else if( h > 23){
            h = h - 24;
        }

        if(h >= 8 && h < 18){
            that.clockBackgroundColor = 'slds-theme_success';
        }else{
            that.clockBackgroundColor = 'slds-theme_error';
        }

        if (h >= 12) {
            h = h > 12 ?  h - 12 : h;
            session = "PM";
        }

        if (h == 0) { //Midnight
            h = 12;
        }


        h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
        m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
        s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

        var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
        var clockEle = that.template.querySelector("div.clock");

        if(clockEle){
            clockEle.innerText = time;
        }

        return true;


}

const Clock = {
    updateClock: updateClock
}

export {Clock}
```

> I did come up with a way to make it work but honestly it feels all wrong. Surely there has be a better way to do this...

To make it work I added the line:

`let uc = function(){Clock.updateClock(this,utcos);}.bind(this);`

to the `startClock` method and replace the places where I was calling `Clock.updateClock` with `uc` making it like this:

```
startClock() {


        let utcos = getFieldValue(this.accountRecord, 'Account.UTC_Offset_Minutes__c') | 0;
        let uc = function(){Clock.updateClock(this,utcos);}.bind(this);

        if(uc) {
            this.timeIntervalInstance = setInterval(uc, 1000)
        }else{
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is `UTC_Offset_Minutes__c` and `GoogleAPI_Exception_Message__c`?

Comment: Not relevant to the issue. Just fields on the record

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are doing, both are just number fields?

Comment: Number and Text. But they are not relevant to the issue other than I am passing one in and referencing the other. I could not use get field value in the export function so I just passed it in.

Comment: I understand they are not relevant - just trying to understand - using other double and text (Name) fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reusable methods are meant to do re-usable processing and not really meant to modify DOM *i.e.,* Not all the classes which import `clock` will have `div.clock` element. Although, you can make it work by `binding`, I think there are better ways to do this.

Below are the 2 ways in which you can implement `Clock`:

**1. Just do processing in `Clock` module and return the processed time:**

Clock module:

```
const updateClock = (utcOffset = 0) => {
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getUTCHours(); // 0 - 23
    var m = date.getUTCMinutes(); // 0 - 59
    var s = date.getUTCSeconds(); // 0 - 59
    var o = utcOffset;

    var hAdj = o / 60;
    var session = 'AM';

    //Local Hour
    h = h + hAdj;

    //Rollover code
    if (h < 0) {
        h = 24 + h;
    } else if (h > 23) {
        h = h - 24;
    }

    if (h >= 12) {
        h = h > 12 ? h - 12 : h;
        session = 'PM';
    }

    if (h == 0) {
        //Midnight
        h = 12;
    }

    h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
    m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
    s = s < 10 ? '0' + s : s;

    var time = h + ':' + m + ':' + s + ' ' + session;
    return time;
};
```

and in your main.js:

```
startClock() {
    let utcos = getFieldValue(this.accountRecord, 'Account.NumberofLocations__c') | 0;

    if (Clock.updateClock(utcos)) {
        this.timeIntervalInstance = setInterval(() => {
            var clockEle = this.template.querySelector('div.clock');
            if (clockEle) {
                clockEle.innerText = Clock.updateClock(utcos);
            }
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

**2. Use extended base class if you want the DOM modification in more than 1 place. In this case it is specific that we want to extend the DOM manipulation functionality as well.**

Base.js:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { Clock } from 'c/utils';

export default class Base extends LightningElement {
    showClock(utcos) {
        if (Clock.updateClock(utcos)) {
            this.timeIntervalInstance = setInterval(() => {
                var clockEle = this.template.querySelector('div.clock');
                if (clockEle) {
                    clockEle.innerText = Clock.updateClock(utcos);
                }
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

main.js:

```
import { wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import Base from 'c/base';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class Poc extends Base {
    timeIntervalInstance;
    accountRecord;

    @api recordId = '00128000009j45qAAA';
    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: '$recordId',
        fields: [ 'Account.Name', 'Account.NumberofLocations__c' ]
    })
    dataLoaded(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.accountRecord = result.data;
            this.startClock();
        }
    }

    startClock() {
        let utcos = getFieldValue(this.accountRecord, 'Account.NumberofLocations__c') | 0;
        this.showClock(utcos);
    }

    get errorMsg() {
        return getFieldValue(this.accountRecord, 'Account.GoogleAPI_Exception_Message__c');
    }
}
```

You can as well implement the whole logic in `Base` class instead of re-usable `utils` module.

Comment: Thanks. You hit the nail on the head with trying to do things in a util class that should not be handled by the util class. Appreciate the fresh set of eyes as mine were clouded with frustration.

Comment: sure @Eric. WC :)